# Maven profiles for different environments - bad practice?

Tags: java, maven

I have several projects where I use maven profile to adapt configuration values for different environments: develop, testing, pre-production, ...

I know that using maven to create different artifacts from the same code is a bad practice. Instead, it is better to have a project with several modules each of them with specific configuration.

I think this is ok when you want to change Java code, for example, when you want to inject different implementations of a bean (*one per client*). But in my case it is only a matter of properties configuration.

- Is it really a bad practice?
- Is it worth to me to change projects configuration from profiles to modules?
- What is the real benefit?

Comment: Is it really a bad practice?- No, thats what profiles are for.

Comment: The problem with profiles in relationship with environments is the following: If you build for which environment do you build? A build should always produce all artifacts which means in other words produce the artifacts for all environments. Furthermore if you like to combine things like building for dev, testing, prod etc. Does that work correctly ? And in the end it is bad practice...

Comment: I personally can't image a world in which you don't go from DEV to TEST to PROD with the same binaries. So yeah, I think it's a pretty bad practice for anything other than config especially for manipulating your upstream dependencies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to what @khmarbaise said in a comment, profiles should only be used to change the **way** the artifacts are built, **not** the artifacts themselves.

Examples of good profile usages I can think of :

- using different repos depending on the build machine
- compiler options depending on the build machine or to build a degraded DEV/TEST version
- run or not some time consuming tests
- configuration for integration tests (which port, which db to use, ...)
- ...

Client/Customer differences and injections choices should always go in configuration.

Your configuration could be maintained in a single place, for all modules, each one using only the keys related to itself.

Comment: Thanks, this is very clarifying